# what does these ejabberd info log messages mean?

Tags: xmpp, chat, ejabberd

can anyone tell me what does these log messages mean? is any session been terminated ,why?

```
2016-01-20 15:48:24.651 [info] <0.477.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:333  (#Port<0.16235>) Accepted connection 192.16.35.6:1432 -> 28.4.5.2
2016-01-20 15:48:27.497 [info] <0.1411.0>@ejabberd_c2s:wait_for_feature_request:740 ({socket_state,p1_tls,{tlssock,#Port<0.16235>,#Port<0.16236>},<0.1410.0>}) Accepted authentication for 14512843168518 by ejabberd_auth_odbc from 103.233.119.62
2016-01-20 15:48:27.903 [info] <0.1411.0>@ejabberd_c2s:wait_for_session:1106 ({socket_state,p1_tls,{tlssock,#Port<0.16235>,#Port<0.16236>},<0.1410.0>}) Opened session for 14512843168518@cndivneofveofv/androidjc1PGFLG
2016-01-20 15:48:27.906 [info] <0.1355.0>@ejabberd_c2s:terminate:1768 ({socket_state,p1_tls,{tlssock,#Port<0.16227>,#Port<0.16228>},<0.1354.0>}) Replaced session for 14512843168518@cedefjwojffj/androidjc1PGFLG
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the user `14512843168518@devchat.drooly.co` had an open session with resource `androidjc1PGFLG`, and this session was terminated and replaced by a new session with the same resource.

This is a feature of XMPP: if a user's client has lost its connection to the XMPP server, but the server hasn't detected it yet, the client can force the server to terminate the previous connection by connecting again and specifying the same resource.

Comment: is there anything to worry about?

Comment: No, it's quite normal.

Comment: and I'veone more doubt, why does client takes a bit time to connect to jabber server. Is there anything we can improve that connectivity problem?

Comment: Measure it: dump the network traffic with a tool like Wireshark, and see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: i have used wireshark, but don't know how to do this. Client is an android app, server is on aws. can you give me little start ?

Comment: set resume_timeout in ejabberd configuration  file   it will save time of creating new session every time if client lost connection because session creation takes server resource and effect server performance. for detail  check this link http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#listening-ports